# Docker container fails to answer respond to HTTP request from host machine

Tags: apache2, docker, nginx, network-bridge, https

I want to deploy an API on a server (Ubuntu 18.04) with Docker (container: Ubuntu 22.04). I previously deployed the API with the same config on another server without any issue.

While being built successfully and having normal logs, the container doesn't seem to receive HTTP requests (container name: `demowebsiteapi` / IP address: 172.17.0.2).

```bash
curl 172.17.0.2:8001/test # => timeout response
curl 127.0.0.1:8001/test # => HTML output for 404 errors
docker exec -it demowebsiteapi /bin/bash
/home/demowebsite# wget -qO- localhost:8001/test
> {"response":"ok"}
```

All (I tried many) the ports on the localhost of the machine output the same HTML for 404 errors. I cannot find the server config file where this response is set; `/etc/apache2/` only contains a file `javascript-common.conf` and `sudo find / -type d -name '.htaccess'` outputs nothing.

> ##### What might be causing the container to not receive HTTP requests? Could there be any interactions or configurations impacting the accessibility of the container? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or debug this issue further?

Here are some more information on my set up:

---

#### Docker configuration

Here is a sample the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV USER demowebsite

...

COPY /docker-confs/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/demowebsite.conf

EXPOSE 8001

CMD export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 && export LANG=C.UTF-8 && \
    source venv/bin/activate && \
    supervisord -c api/docker-confs/supervisord.conf
```

And a sample of the script that builds the container:

```bash
docker build --rm -t demowebsiteapi . -f Dockerfile --build-arg USERID="$DEMO_UID";

docker rm demowebsiteapi

docker run -d --name demowebsiteapi \
   -v $DATA_FOLDER:/data/ -p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001 \
   --restart unless-stopped --ipc=host demowebsiteapi
```

Sample of the NetworkSettings (`docker inspect demowebsiteapi`):

```json
"NetworkSettings": {
    ...
    "Ports": {
        "8001/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                "HostPort": "8001"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Networks": {
        "bridge": {
            ...
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
}
```

Weirdly, duplicated processes seem to run at the same time for the Docker

```bash
$ ps aux | grep demowebsite
userme  10534  0.0  0.0  28140 21484 ?        S    13:53   0:00 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/python3 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/website.sock app.main:app --worker-connections 1001 --workers 4
userme  10563  0.5  0.2 3890376 381392 ?      Sl   13:53   0:03 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/python3 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/website.sock app.main:app --worker-connections 1001 --workers 4
userme  10567  0.5  0.2 3890220 381952 ?      Sl   13:53   0:03 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/python3 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/website.sock app.main:app --worker-connections 1001 --workers 4
userme  10538  0.0  0.0 104748 24676 ?        Sl   13:53   0:00 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/python3 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/dramatiq app.main -p 1 -t 1
userme  10566  0.6  0.2 4186140 379588 ?      Sl   13:53   0:04 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/python3 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/dramatiq app.main -p 1 -t 1
userme  10800  0.0  0.0  31188 18580 ?        S    13:54   0:00 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/python3 /home/demowebsite/venv/bin/dramatiq app.main -p 1 -t 1
```

---

#### Network setup

```bash
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

$ sudo ufw app list
Available applications:
  CUPS
  OpenSSH

$ netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   
...

$ ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
```

---

###### Thank you so much for your help, I have been stuck on this problem for a week now and any advice or insight on the issue would be highly valuable!

---

#### Edit: more info

Output of `docker ps`

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
430796e48525   demowebsiteapi   "/bin/bash -c 'expor…"   12 hours ago   Up 27 minutes   0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp   demowebsiteapi
```

I noticed `iptables` config is odd, i tried to reset it but on reboot, it rollback to the same setup

```bash
sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4173 packets, 508K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 753 packets, 111K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8001

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: What's the output of `docker ps`? Please include in your question.

Comment: CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
430796e48525   demowebsiteapi   "/bin/bash -c 'expor…"   47 minutes ago   Up 47 minutes   0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp   demowebsiteapi

Comment: In your question, please...

Comment: Could you try and run the same container on a new clean server, preferably not Ubuntu 18.04, but instead Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04. Ubuntu 18.04 is actually EOL, so running anything on Ubuntu 18.04 is both off-topic here and not recommended. If your Docker config works on another server, then the issue might be near impossible to troubleshoot, since it will be some server specific issue on your current (outdated) server.

Comment: This is exactly what I intend to do! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your script for building the container, when you run:

```
docker run -d --name demowebsiteapi \
   -v $DATA_FOLDER:/data/ -p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001 \
   --restart unless-stopped --ipc=host demowebsiteapi
```

Which matches your `netstat` output:

```
$ netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

When you prefix the port with the `localhost` address (`-p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001`), the published port is only accessible from `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`), which `netstat` also shows.

Instead, configure the port for any IP address, like this:

```
docker run -d --name demowebsiteapi \
   -v $DATA_FOLDER:/data/ -p 8001:8001 \
   --restart unless-stopped --ipc=host demowebsiteapi
```

In this case, `netstat` should also properly show:

```
$ netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

See the [Docker Networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Unfortunately I have already tried this solution and the problem persists.. I still get timeout response on the container IP and 404 html response on localhost. `netstat` response: `tcp6    0    0   :::8001    :::*.   LISTEN`

Comment: Ok that's a little odd..